# How to make link emacs button work on mouse click in another buffer?

Tags: button, emacs, elisp, emacs24

I use GNU emacs-24.
I make button like this:

```
(defun go-click (button)
  (print (button-get button 'point))
  (let ((win (get-buffer-window (button-get button 'buffer))))
    (if win
        (progn
          (select-window win)
          (goto-char (button-get button 'point)))
      (message "open a window with the location"))))

(let ((p (point)) (buf (current-buffer)))
  (with-current-buffer (get-buffer "yyy")
    (insert-button "go" 'action #'go-click
                   'follow-link t
                   'point p
                   'buffer buf)))
```

I have this code in ***scratch*** buffer in onw window and another window with bufffer **yyy**. I eval-current-buffer while the point is, say on #'go-click position. And the button *go* in **yyy** appears.

If I now click on the button, it prints the number, as expected, makes ***scratch*** active, as supposed, but doesn't move the point on #'go-click position.

But if I position point on the *go* button by cursor keys, and hit enter, it works as expected (moves point to #'go-click positoin, no matter, where I left it in ***scratch*** previously) .

How to make it work for both keyboard-enter and mouse-click scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the little patch:

```
(defun go-click (button)
  (print (button-get button 'point))
  (let ((win (get-buffer-window (button-get button 'buffer)))
        (cur-win (get-buffer-window (current-buffer))))
    (select-window cur-win)
    (if win
        (progn
          (select-window win)
          (goto-char (button-get button 'point)))
      (message "open a window with the location"))))
```

Comment: I suppose in mouse-click scenario `point` is in **\*scratch\*** buffer and after all manipulations emacs just restore the point. I use `debug-on-entry` for function `goto-char` to clarify behavior.